# How to add different text underneath each box on this slider/carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I was wondering how I would add new text at the bottom of each box on this code:

https://codepen.io/sub0-l3/pen/xjPwBP

I wanted to make it clear that I don't want new text in the box, but underneath the box. Each box would have a different text. So basically when you press the left or right arrows it will show new next along with the boxes. Thank you!

```js
function shiftLeft() {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    const tmpNode = boxes[0];
    boxes[0].className = "box move-out-from-left";

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (boxes.length > 5) {
            tmpNode.classList.add("box--hide");
            boxes[5].className = "box move-to-position5-from-left";
        }
        boxes[1].className = "box move-to-position1-from-left";
        boxes[2].className = "box move-to-position2-from-left";
        boxes[3].className = "box move-to-position3-from-left";
        boxes[4].className = "box move-to-position4-from-left";
        boxes[0].remove();

        document.querySelector(".cards__container").appendChild(tmpNode);

    }, 500);

}

function shiftRight() {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    boxes[4].className = "box move-out-from-right";
    setTimeout(function() {
        const noOfCards = boxes.length;
        if (noOfCards > 4) {
            boxes[4].className = "box box--hide";
        }

        const tmpNode = boxes[noOfCards - 1];
        tmpNode.classList.remove("box--hide");
        boxes[noOfCards - 1].remove();
        let parentObj = document.querySelector(".cards__container");
        parentObj.insertBefore(tmpNode, parentObj.firstChild);
        tmpNode.className = "box move-to-position1-from-right";
        boxes[0].className = "box move-to-position2-from-right";
        boxes[1].className = "box move-to-position3-from-right";
        boxes[2].className = "box move-to-position4-from-right";
        boxes[3].className = "box move-to-position5-from-right";
    }, 500);

}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.button {
    margin-left: 0 3%;
    width: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button--inactive {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.button img {
    width: 60%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.cards__container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 25rem;
}

.box {
/*     margin: -1.5rem; */
    width: 12rem;
    height: 20rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2rem 0px #888888;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    /* transition: 1s all; */
}

.box:nth-child(2n) {
    transform: scale(0.85);
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  left: 5%;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  left: -5%;
}

.box:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    z-index: -2;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  left: 15%;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  left: -15%;
}

.card__text-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}

.card__title {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.box--hide {
    display: none;
}

.move-out-from-left {
    animation: moveOutLeft 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-out-from-right {
    animation: moveOutRight 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position5-from-left {
    animation: moveToP5Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position4-from-left {
    animation: moveToP4Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position3-from-left {
    animation: moveToP3Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position2-from-left {
    animation: moveToP2Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.move-to-position1-from-left{
    animation: moveToP1Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position5-from-right{
    animation: moveToP5Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position4-from-right{
    animation: moveToP4Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position3-from-right{
    animation: moveToP3Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position2-from-right{
    animation: moveToP2Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position1-from-right{
    animation: moveToP1Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes moveOutLeft {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-150%);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.25) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes moveOutRight {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.5) translateX(150%);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.25) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}


@keyframes moveToP5Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP4Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP3Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP2Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP1Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}


@keyframes moveToP1Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP2Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP3Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP4Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP5Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>3d-carousal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="button" onclick="shiftLeft()"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/mRsEb7/left_arrow.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cards-wrapper">
            <ul class="cards__container">
                <li class="box" style="background-color:red">box 1
              </li>
                <li class="box">box 2</li>
                <li class="box">box 3</li>
                <li class="box">box 4</li>
                <li class="box">box 5</li>
                <li class="box box--hide">box 6</li>
                <li class="box box--hide">box 7</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">The Famous Five</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button" onclick="shiftRight()"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/dfPSw7/right_arrow.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src='js/index.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: doh! the slider isn't working

Comment: @gofish1234 Do you mean that you want the change the text "The Famous Five" and the excerpt underneath it?

Comment: @Viira it works if you expand the page

Comment: @JaredChu Yes something like that. I would like that text to change every time I click the arrows.

Comment: oops my bad! thought it was a drag-able slider

Comment: @Viira no worries!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do that (jQuery data binding, Vue.js, React.js), but if you want a simple way that uses pure JavaScript, here is it:

1. Set ID for every single box like `box1` `box2` `boxn`...
2. Each box will have its corresponding `card__text-content` with ID `databox1` `databox2`...
3. Show or hide corresponding `card__text-content` with the centered box

```js
showBoxData('box3');
function shiftLeft() {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    const tmpNode = boxes[0];
    boxes[0].className = "box move-out-from-left";

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (boxes.length > 5) {
            tmpNode.classList.add("box--hide");
            boxes[5].className = "box move-to-position5-from-left";
        }
        boxes[1].className = "box move-to-position1-from-left";
        boxes[2].className = "box move-to-position2-from-left";
        boxes[3].className = "box move-to-position3-from-left";
        boxes[4].className = "box move-to-position4-from-left";
        boxes[0].remove();

        document.querySelector(".cards__container").appendChild(tmpNode);

    }, 500);
    showBoxData(boxes[3].id);
}

function shiftRight() {
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    boxes[4].className = "box move-out-from-right";
    setTimeout(function() {
        const noOfCards = boxes.length;
        if (noOfCards > 4) {
            boxes[4].className = "box box--hide";
        }

        const tmpNode = boxes[noOfCards - 1];
        tmpNode.classList.remove("box--hide");
        boxes[noOfCards - 1].remove();
        let parentObj = document.querySelector(".cards__container");
        parentObj.insertBefore(tmpNode, parentObj.firstChild);
        tmpNode.className = "box move-to-position1-from-right";
        boxes[0].className = "box move-to-position2-from-right";
        boxes[1].className = "box move-to-position3-from-right";
        boxes[2].className = "box move-to-position4-from-right";
        boxes[3].className = "box move-to-position5-from-right";
    }, 500);
    showBoxData(boxes[1].id);
}

function showBoxData(boxId) {
  // hide all data
  document.querySelectorAll(".card__text-content").forEach(function(node) {
    if('data' + boxId !== node.id){
      node.style.display = 'none';  
     }
    else{
      node.style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
}
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.button {
    margin-left: 0 3%;
    width: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button--inactive {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.button img {
    width: 60%;
}

.cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.cards__container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 25rem;
}

.box {
/*     margin: -1.5rem; */
    width: 12rem;
    height: 20rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2rem 0px #888888;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    /* transition: 1s all; */
}

.box:nth-child(2n) {
    transform: scale(0.85);
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  left: 5%;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  left: -5%;
}

.box:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    z-index: -2;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  left: 15%;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  left: -15%;
}

.card__text-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}

.card__title {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.box--hide {
    display: none;
}

.move-out-from-left {
    animation: moveOutLeft 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-out-from-right {
    animation: moveOutRight 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position5-from-left {
    animation: moveToP5Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position4-from-left {
    animation: moveToP4Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position3-from-left {
    animation: moveToP3Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position2-from-left {
    animation: moveToP2Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.move-to-position1-from-left{
    animation: moveToP1Left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.move-to-position5-from-right{
    animation: moveToP5Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position4-from-right{
    animation: moveToP4Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position3-from-right{
    animation: moveToP3Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position2-from-right{
    animation: moveToP2Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.move-to-position1-from-right{
    animation: moveToP1Right 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes moveOutLeft {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-150%);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.25) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes moveOutRight {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(0.5) translateX(150%);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.25) translateX(0%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}


@keyframes moveToP5Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP4Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP3Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP2Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP1Left {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}


@keyframes moveToP1Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP2Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP3Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP4Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(1) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveToP5Right {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.85) translateX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(0.75) translateX(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>3d-carousal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="button" onclick="shiftLeft()"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/mRsEb7/left_arrow.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cards-wrapper">
            <ul class="cards__container">
                <li id="box1" class="box" style="background-color:red">box 1</li>
                <li id="box2" class="box">box 2</li>
                <li id="box3" class="box">box 3</li>
                <li id="box4" class="box">box 4</li>
                <li id="box5" class="box">box 5</li>
                <li id="box6" class="box box--hide">box 6</li>
                <li id="box7" class="box box--hide">box 7</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="databox1" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 1 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox2" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 2 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox3" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 3 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox4" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 4 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox5" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 5 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox6" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 6 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
          <div id="databox7" class="card__text-content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Box 7 title</h3>
                <div class="card__summary">The Famous Five is a series of children's adventure novels written by English author Enid Blyton. The first book, Five on a Treasure Island, was published in 1942.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button" onclick="shiftRight()"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/dfPSw7/right_arrow.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src='js/index.js'></script>
</body>
```